# How to use dictionaries in a generic custom class

Tags: swift, generics, collections

I want to use Dictionary as a member reference of a custom class but I've some problems to understand how to define it with generics.
I have the following Swift code:

```
public class MyDictionary<K,V> {
  private var dict : Dictionary<K,V>

  public init() {
    dict = Dictionary<K,V>()
  }
}
```

Later in my app I want to create dictionaries with several types:

```
dict1 = MyDictionary<Int,String>()
dict2 = MyDictionary<String,MyCustomClass>()
...
```

Where is my error in reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Hashable types can be stored as the key of a Swift Dictionary:

```
class MyDictionary<Key : Hashable, ValueType> {
    private var dict : Dictionary<Key,ValueType>

    internal init() {
        dict = Dictionary<Key,ValueType>()
    }
}

var dict1 = MyDictionary<Int,String>()
var dict2 = MyDictionary<String,String>()
```